# Group by on three tables as one master table and two detail tables

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by

### I.tblOwnerDetails

| Ownerid | ownername |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Abc |
| 2 | Xyz |
| 3 | Pqr |

### II.tblListMaster

| Listid | Listname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | List1 |
| 2 | List2 |

### III.tblListDetails

| Detailid | Listid | Ownerid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |

### IV.tblTagMaster

| TagId | Tagname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tag1 |
| 2 | tag2 |

### V.tblTagDetails

| Detailid | Tagid | Ownerid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |

Result i want as

| Ownerid | Listcount | Tagcount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

This is the query I've tried so far:

```
with cte_ListCount as
(
    Select o.Ownerid,
           Count(ld.OwnerId) as ListCount
    from tblOwnerDetails o
        inner join tblListDetail ld
            on o.OwnerId = ld.OwnerId
        inner join tblListMaster lm
            on lm.ListId = ld.ListId group by o.ownerid),
cte_TagCount as
(
    select o.ownerid,
           COUNT(td.OwnerId) as TagCount
        from  tblOwnerDetails o 
        left join tblTagDetail td
            on o.OwnerId = td.OwnerId
        inner join tblTagMaster tm
            on tm.TagId = td.TagId
        group by o.ownerid
)
select o.ownerid,
       ISNULL(clc.ListCount, 0) as ListCount,
       ISNULL(ctc.TagCount, 0) as TagCount
from tblOwnerDetails o
left join cte_ListCount clc
    on clc.OwnerId = o.OwnerId
left join cte_TagCount ctc
    on ctc.OwnerId = o.OwnerId
```

Comment: Select o. Ownerid, count(td.Tagid) as Tagcount, count(ld.listid) as listcount from mastertable o join detaillist ld on o.ownerid = ld.ownerid left join detailtag tld on o.ownerid = tld.ownerid group by o.ownerid

Comment: I want the count of ownerid present in detaillist as well as detailtag table.

Comment: please update your question with the query and additional information. It is harder to read the query in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the query you've tried so far, you're probably running into an issue with incorrect counts because you're joining two *one-to-many* tables on the *many* side of the relationship for both resulting in a *many-to-many* join.

Instead, one way you can accomplish your goal is to roll up each table individually first as two separate queries, and then join the results together like so:

```
WITH CTE_DetailList_Count AS -- Group up the Detail List and count them
(
    SELECT 
        Ownerid, 
        COUNT(listid) AS ListCount
    FROM detaillist
    GROUP BY ownerid
),
CTE_DetailTag_Count AS -- Group up the Detail Tags and count them
(
    SELECT 
        Ownerid, 
        COUNT(Tagid) AS TagCount
    FROM detailtag
    GROUP BY ownerid
)

-- Final results
SELECT 
    MT.Ownerid,
    ISNULL(DLC.ListCount, 0) AS ListCount,
    ISNULL(DTC.TagCount, 0) AS TagCount
FROM mastertable AS MT
LEFT JOIN CTE_DetailList_Count AS DLC
    ON MT.Ownerid = DLC.Ownerid
LEFT JOIN CTE_DetailTag_Count AS DTC
    ON MT.Ownerid = DTC.Ownerid
```